# Question about limits at infinity.

Tags: limits

if for example I have fucntions $f$ and $g$, we've prove in class that if
$$\lim _{x\to a}\left(f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right)=L$$

$$or$$

$$\lim _{x\to a}\left(f\left(x\right)\cdot g\left(x\right)\right)=L$$

then both limits of $f$ and $g$ exist, or both don't exist.

but what about

$$\lim _{x\to ∞/-∞}\left(f\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)\right)=L$$

$$or$$

$$\lim _{x\to ∞/-∞}\left(f\left(x\right)\cdot g\left(x\right)\right)=L$$

Does it still hold that both of f,g must exist or both must not exist?
If so, how do I prove it?

Comment: Have you try to apply the same proof? It may work.

Comment: $L\neq 0$ for the limit of the product, isn't it? Because taking $a=0$, $L=0$, $f(x)=x^2$, $g(x)=1/x$, we have $f(x)g(x)\to 0$ but only $f$ has a limit at $0$. By the way, taking $a=0$, $L=1\neq 0$, $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=1/x$, we have $f(x)g(x)\to 1$ but again only $f$ has a limit at $0$.

Comment: Does $\boxed{x \to \infty / -\infty}$ just mean that you don't care about if it's $+\infty$ or $-\infty ?$

Answer (score 0):

The point to which the limit tends is indeed irrelevant. By a change of variable such that $t:=a+\dfrac1x$, you turn a limit to infinity in a limit at any $a$.

Anyway, your notation $\lim_{x\to\infty/-\infty}$ is ambiguous.